# Ensure string has a breaking character every n chars

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way in JavaScript to insert a space character or soft-hyphen character in a string in such a way that you ensure there is no unbreakable substring longer than a maximum length specified? I'm having problems with long strings not wrapping properly in some of my HTML tables and would like a function that takes as input a string and a maximum number of characters and the breaking character to insert. The function should not insert the breaking character unless necessary.

(I know you can use CSS to force wrapping but that doesn't always work so need this as a backup).

The input string isn't necessarily made up of only digits and Latin characters, it could be Cyrillic, Chinese, Arabic... Is this even possible?

I'm presuming you could use regex to look if there are strings longer than n chars that don't end in a space or hyphen character...

Something like:

```
myBreakFunc(s, maxChars, insertBreakChar) {...}
```

such that for example:

```
myBreakFunc("Onetwothreefour", 3, '&shy') = "One-two-thr-eef-our"

myBreakFunc("One two three four", 3, ' ') = "One two thr ee fou r"

mybreakFunc("The quick brown fox", 5, ' ') = "The quick brown fox" // nothing to do as there are no strings longer than 5 chars without a space or hyphen

myBreakFunc("The quick-brownfox", 5, ' ') = "The quick-brown fox"
```

Comment: Yup. What have you tried so far? We need to see _your_ code and any problems you've had.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why CSS and normal text wrapping "doesn't always work"? When does it work, and when does it cause you problems (and why)?

Comment: I've managed to do it myself with a somewhat clunky javascript function:

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you can resume it to:

- Let ***`x`*** be ***`breakChar`*** characters.
- Let ***`[^x]`*** be *non-**`breakChar`*** characters.
- Let ***`n`*** be ***`maxChars`*** number.

Find ***`[^x]`*** subsequences of length ***`n`*** which has ahead another ***`[^x]`***, then insert ***`x`*** after it.

Here is the generic regular expression in a replace method:

```
str = str.replace(/[^x]{n}(?=[^x])/g, '$&x');
```

You can easily write a function using `RegExp` constructor to generate the above pattern for custom ***`x`*** and ***`n`***.

---

Here is an example:

```js
function myBreakFunc(str, n, x) {
    var pattern = RegExp(`[^${x}]{${n}}(?=[^${x}])`, 'g');
    return str.replace(pattern, '$&' + x)
}


var res = myBreakFunc("One two three four", 3, ' ');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a string of Cyrillic characters without any spaces in it.

It also doesn't handle this string:
"YayThelongestnameeverandnospacspacesinitThelongeYayThelongestnameeverandnospacspacesinitThelongeYayThelongestnameeverandnospacspacesinitThelongeYayThelongestnameeverandnospacspacesinitThelongeYayThelongestnameeverandnospacspacesinitThelonge89890808908989808908089089090808908900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my javascript function:

```
function forceBreaks(s, ch, maxLen) {
    var ret = "";
    var index = 0;
    var shyChar = String.fromCharCode(0xAD);
    while (index < s.length) {
        // get the first substring of size maxLen+1
        s1 = s.substr(index,maxLen+1);
        // if there are no breaking characters insert ch character (eg a soft-hyphen) at the end of the string
        var i1 = s1.indexOf(' ');
        var i2 = s1.indexOf('-');
        var i3 = s1.indexOf(shyChar);
        if (i1 == -1 && i2 == -1 && i3 == -1) {
            s1 = s.substr(index, maxLen);
            ret += s1 + ch;
            index += maxLen;
        }
        else {
            var lastBreakCharIndex = Math.max(i1, i2, i3);
            ret += s1.substr(0,lastBreakCharIndex+1);
            index += lastBreakCharIndex+1;
        }
    }

    // remove the trailing ch character if we added one to the end
    if (ret.charAt( ret.length-1 ) == ch) {
        ret = ret.slice(0, -1)
    }
    return ret;
};
```

It does the trick but I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing it.